# Simple HTML Dom failing

Tags: php, html

I have the following code trying to extract the 'photo swipe' section of the site.
It has three separate classes bx-wrapper built - class=bx-viewport - view.

The first two return blank. The view class return an image of the vehicle.
I have searched stack overflow with ref to the spaces and I presume I have the syntax correct for the classes with spaces.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.

```
<?php 
require('simple_html_dom.php');
set_time_limit(0);
if (!$html = file_get_html('http://www.citroen.co.uk/new-cars-and-vans/citroen-range/citroen-c3-picasso')) 
        {
  $error = error_get_last();
  echo "HTTP request failed. Error was: " . $error['message'];
        } 
            else 
        {
        //echo "The HTML exists so we can use find......";
        //echo $html;
    //foreach($html->find('div[class="bx-wrapper built"]') as $itemtitle) {
    //foreach($html->find('div[class=bx-viewport]') as $itemtitle) {
    foreach($html->find('div[class=view]') as $itemtitle) 
    {   
        echo $itemtitle;
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: Probally which the content is generated by javascript

Answer (score 0):

The 'photo swipe' sections is not part of the response from **http://www.citroen.co.uk/new-cars-and-vans/citroen-range/citroen-c3-picasso**, you have to figure out which script is rendering that part.

Hint: view the reponse source code (view-source:http://www.citroen.co.uk/new-cars-and-vans/citroen-range/citroen-c3-picasso) and see the section

```
    <div class="larger" >
        <script type="text/template" class="viewTpl">
           <div class="views">
                <% if(imgs.length > 0) { %>
                    <% _.each(imgs,function(img,i){ %>
                    <div class="view"<% if(bgs[i]){ %> style="background-image:url(<%= bgs[i] %>);" data-img="<%= bgs[i] %>"<% }; %>>


                    <img class="car" src="<%= img %>" width="717" height="438" alt="" />


                    </div>
                    <% }); %>
                <% } else { %>
                    <% _.each(bgs,function(bg,i){ %>
                    <div class="view" style="background-image:url(<%= bg %>);" data-img="<%= bg %>"></div>
                    <% }); %>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is way above my head now. I have searched on extracting javascript rendering using simple_html_dom but could not find anything relevant. Can you elaborate on what I need to do .